# How to manage shutdown of ExecutorService when we allow to inject it?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, resources, resource-cleanup

Suppose I am writing a service, which needs some executor service/separate thread. **I give ability to use factory method to not worry about executor service, but still want to allow passing existing executor service** (dependency injection).

**How can I manage for `executorService.shutdown()`?**

Example code:

```
public class ThingsScheduler {

    private final ExecutorService executorService;

    public ThingsScheduler(ExecutorService executorService) {
        this.executorService = executorService;
    }

    public static ThingsScheduler createDefaultSingleThreaded() {
        return new ThingsScheduler(Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor());
    }

    public scheduleThing() {
        executorService.submit(new SomeTask());
    }

    // implement Closeable?
    // @PreDestory?
    // .shutdown() + JavaDoc?
}
```

There are several problems

- We should have ability to shutdown internally created executor, or in best case handle it automatically (Spring @PreDestory, or in worst case finalize())
- We shold rather not shutdown executor if it's externally managed (injected)

We could create some attribute stating if executor is created by our class or if it's injected, and then on finalize/@PreDestroy/shutdown hook we could shut down it, but it not feels elegant for me.

Maybe we should completely resign from factory method and always require injection pushing executor lifecycle management to the client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some more thinking I came up with some conclusions:

- **do not** think about shutting it down if it's injected - someone else created it, someone else will manage it's lifecycle
- an **executor factory** could be injected instead of Executor, then we create instance using factory and manage closing it by ourself as we manage the lifecycle (and in such case responses from other users applies)

Comment: Fixing the first point and ignoring the second point of factories (or suppliers) for now. What was your way of differentiating between injected executors and internally created executors? I assume you would go with something like:

`if executorService was injected: do not close; else: close;`

At which case you still have to advertise your `ThingsScheduler` as `AutoCloseable`. Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

You may crate an instance of anonymous sub-inner class from your default factory as shown below. The class will define the close/@PreDestroy method which shall be called by your DI container.
e.g.

```
public class ThingsScheduler {
    final ExecutorService executorService;

    public ThingsScheduler(ExecutorService executorService) {
        this.executorService = executorService;
    }

    /**
     * assuming you are using this method as factory method to make the returned
     * bean as managed by your DI container
     */
    public static ThingsScheduler createDefaultSingleThreaded() {
        return new ThingsScheduler(Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()) {
            @PreDestroy
            public void close() {
                System.out.println("closing the bean");
                executorService.shutdown();
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Kind of like this solution, only drawback is that it's high coupled with Spring API

Answer (score 1):

I would say that solution in fully up to you. Third-party libraries like spring widely use a dedicated attribute to understand who should release a particular resource depending on its creator. `mongoInstanceCreated` in [SimpleMongoDbFactory](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-mongodb/blob/master/spring-data-mongodb/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/SimpleMongoDbFactory.java), `localServer` in [SimpleHttpServerJaxWsServiceExporter](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/remoting/jaxws/SimpleHttpServerJaxWsServiceExporter.java), etc. But they do it because these classes are created only for external usage. If your class is only used in your application code than you can either inject `executorService` and don't care about its releasing or create and release it inside the class which uses it. This choice depends on your class/application design (does your class work with any `executorService`, whether `executorService` is shared and used by other classes, etc). Otherwise i don't see other option than the dedicated flag.

Answer (score 0):

More "elegant" solution would be to extend your ExecutorService and in it override shutdown method (whichever you choose). In case of injection, you would return that extended type and it would have it's own shutdown logic. In case of factory - you still have original logic.